# How do you install a graphics card on mac pro 1,1?

Tags: mac-pro, gpu, compatibility

Howdo you install a Radeon 6000 series graphics card on mac pro 1,1?

Comment: like specifically anything from the Radeon 6000 series

Comment: Is this a "Mac" GPU or a common one for BIOS-based PCs? I remember reading that the Mac Pro 1,1 is limited when it comes to using BIOS-based GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to install since OS X has the drivers predelivered. You pull out the old one and stick in the new one. [https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Pro+Graphic+Card+for+Mac+Pro+(Early+2008)+Replacement/14161](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Pro+Graphic+Card+for+Mac+Pro+%28Early+2008%29+Replacement/14161)

Comment: It depends on which version of OS X if it's not a Mac GPU.

Comment: Thanks, so does this process work for the mid-2006 model as well as the early-2008 model?